# How do I disable Swiper while defining a keyboard macro?

Tags: keyboard-macros, swiper

I don't like the swiper behavior when interactively defining a macro, it is slow and seems to cause other problems. How can I revert bound keys to `isearch-forward` and `isearch-backward` when defining macros, but use swiper for all other use cases?

Comment: Note: keyboard macros record the keys typed rather than the commands run, so you'll want to disable swiper not just whie defining the macro but also when running it.